# Background effect with CSS only

Tags: css, design-patterns, background

Anyhow know how I can go about creating a background animation like this with CSS?

[image]

Comment: What is the animation required? And what searching have you done?

Answer (score 0):

You can create two `absolute` html elements and align them left and right accordingly. Then you can apply CSS radial gradient on these elements for example:   `background: radial-gradient(45% 45% at 50% 50%, rgba(77, 230, 219, 0.2) 0%, rgba(77, 230, 219, 0) 100%);` Otherwise, you can use pseudo-elements (`:after, :before`) instead of HTML tags.

**Here is a quick sketch of what you can do:**

```css
.hero {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  background-color: #000;
  position: relative;
}
.hero:after,
.hero:before {
  content: '';
  background: radial-gradient(45% 45% at 50% 50%, rgba(77, 230, 219, 0.2) 0%, rgba(77, 230, 219, 0) 100%);
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
}
.hero:before {
  left: -100px;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
}
.hero:after{
  right: -100px;
  top: 0;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
}
```

```html
<div class="hero"></div>
```

To make life easier, you can use CSS Gradient Generators, such as: https://cssgradient.io/